# How can I add captions to this auto-create php gallery?

Tags: php, gallery

```
<?php        
    /* settings */  
    $image_dir = 'gallery/';  
    $per_column = 3;  
    $count=0;
      if ($handle = opendir($image_dir)) {  
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))  
        {  
            if ($file != '.' && $file != '..')  
            {  
                if(strstr($file,'-thumb'))  
                {  
                    $files[] = $file;  
                }  
            }  
        }  
        closedir($handle);  
    }  
    if(count($files))  
    {  
        foreach($files as $file)  
        {   
            $count++;  
            echo '<a class="thumbnail" rel="one-big-group" href="',$image_dir,str_replace('-thumb','',$file),'"><img src="',$image_dir,$file,'" width="100" height="100" /></a>';  
            if($count % $per_column == 0) { echo '<div class="clear"></div>'; }  
        }  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        echo '<p>There are no images in this gallery.</p>';  
    }  

?>
```

How can I add captions to each of the images?
Thank you very much for the answer!

Comment: What kind of captions? Like where do you get the caption for each picture from?

Comment: That's what I want to know how to do. Writing a caption for each file, and showing it using php in the current script. Is that possible to do with arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is traversing the files within the specified directory looking for files containing `...-thumb...` in the filename, appending them to an array, and then looping over the array to generate HTML for displaying the thumbnail image gallery.

Adding additional information to something like this, given the very limited code you've provided, can be done in any number of ways

1. You could implement a database with a column for each filename and a
   related column containing captions/descriptions. This might be more
   trouble than it's worth depending on what you're trying to achieve.
2. You could use a flat file which you could parse line by line *(instead of traversing the

   folder for `...-thumb...` images)*, containing some format like

   ```
   file1-thumb.png|some caption here
   file2-thumb.png|some caption here
   file3-thumb.png|some caption here
   ...
   ```
3. You could includ a small caption in the filename itself, and parse/format the caption from the filenames. This would probably be the quickest route, but most limiting in terms of flexibility in the length/characters allowed for the captions.

   ```
   - file1-thumb--some_caption_here.png
   - file2-thumb--some_caption_here.png
   - file3-thumb--some_caption_here.png
   ```

To actually add the caption to the generated HTML, you can use a `title` attribute as @rockerest suggested, however I'd personally add such a caption to to the image itself, as that is what the caption is describing *(not the link)*

```
<img src="..." title="..." ... />
```

**UPDATE**

To answer your comment *(this provides better formatting for code)*, Let's say we have a file with name `file1-thumb--some_description_here.jpg`, you can parse and format the caption with [preg_replace](http://us.php.net/preg_replace)

```
$filename = 'file1-thumb--some_description_here.jpg';
$caption = preg_replace(array('/^.+-thumb--/', '/\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$/', '/_/'), array('','',' '), $filename);
```

`$caption` is now *some description here*

Comment: Great tips mate, how can I write the caption in the title? Or how can I remove the .jpeg text if I use str_replace('-thumb','',$file)?

Comment: I will add this to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The html [title](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200412/the_alt_and_title_attributes/) offers a "caption" when the mouse is hovered over the image.

```
foreach($files as $file)  
        {   
            $count++;  
            echo '<a title="',$caption,'" class="thumbnail" rel="one-big-group" href="',$image_dir,str_replace('-thumb','',$file),'"><img src="',$image_dir,$file,'" width="100" height="100" /></a>';  
            if($count % $per_column == 0) { echo '<div class="clear"></div>'; }  
        }
```